# Google Apps Script listbox to dropdown box

Tags: drop-down-menu, listbox, google-apps-script

I'm building a UI in Google Sites using Apps Script and I am able to create a listbox.  According to the documentation if you change the setVisibleItemCount to 1 it will become a dropdown box.

I have tried both 1 and 0.

Neither seems to make it a drop-down box.  Using Firefox 13.0.1 to view.  Have also tried Safari.

Anyone had any luck with this?

Code looks like this:

```
var vPanel = container.createVerticalPanel();
    //List box
    var lb = container.createListBox(true).setId('listbox').setName('listbox');

   // add items to ListBox
   for(var i=0;i<LIST_OF_PROJECTS.length;i++){
       lb.addItem(LIST_OF_PROJECTS[i]);
   }

   vPanel.add(lb);
   lb.setVisibleItemCount(1);  //supposed to make it a drop-down but doesn't

   lb.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

This is all inside a Google Site and the page that is being displayed is a Apps Script Page.  Perhaps you are NOT using Google Sites?  Above code gives me a single line but no drop down arrow.

Comment: Well I use it in a standalone webapp, not in a site but I'll give it a try and let you know ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you post your relevant code please ?, It's working for me on firefox (slightly differently), chrome & safari. (see screen cap when I click the selector, SetVisibleItemCount is 1)

thx

[image]

**EDIT** : One important point : to get the list acting as a dropdown list you have to choose 'disable multiple selection', in other words : createListBox(false) or no parameter... but not 'true' **as it is in your code** !! *(now we know why it doesn't work in your case ;-)*

With this parameter set to false , it works as expected in standalone webapp, embedded on site and linked to spreadsheet without any difference.

Comment: Posted in original post.  Editor down here doesn't like returns!

Comment: see [this test on a google site](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/temp-test)

Answer (score 0):

Don't call:

```
setVisibleItemCount
```

at all.